# $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1-(1-1/n)^4}{1-(1-1/n)^3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Find

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{1-\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^4}{1-\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^3}$$

I can't figure out why the limit is equal to $\dfrac{4}{3}$ because I take the limit of a quotient to be the quotient of their limits.

I'm taking that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}1-\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^4 = 0$ and likewise that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}1-\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^3 = 0$, which still gives me that the limit should be 0.

Comment: The rule your using only applies when the limit of the denominator is not 0. Remember that $0/0$ is undefined.

Comment: Okay thanks! Any rules I should apply first then because I'm still not seeing how each part could possibly be an integer after 1- anything.

Comment: See GabrielH's solution. He is using L'Hospital's rule.

Comment: If you are still early in your course and haven't established "LHR" yet (or are learning how to compute limits without using it -- as many questions on this site do), you may want to go with one of the other two solutions.

Comment: @Arjang It is better not to use things like \dfrac in titles, see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9687/guidelines-for-good-use-of-latex-in-question-titles).

Comment: @MartinSleziak : there was no \dfrac in the title.

Comment: @Arjang Sorry for my mistake then. But the title was still huge in my opinion.

Comment: @MartinSleziak : That was due to browsers initial rendering, I saw it span to muliple lines on page load, but after the page load it collapsed to one line. (I was using chrome on Win 7)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{1-\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^4}{1-\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^3}
\stackrel{\mathscr{L}}{=}\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{4\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^3 \dfrac{1}{n^2}}{3\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^2\dfrac{1}{n^2}}
=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{4\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^3}{3\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^2} = \color{blue}{\dfrac{4}{3}}$$

Answer (score 8):

If you expand the binomials, you get $\dfrac{1-\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^4}{1-\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^3}=\dfrac{1-\left(1-\dfrac{4}{n}+\dfrac{6}{n^2}-\dfrac{4}{n^3}+\dfrac{1}{n^4}\right)}{1-\left(1-\dfrac{3}{n}+\dfrac{3}{n^2}-\dfrac{1}{n^3}\right)}=\dfrac{\dfrac{4}{n}-\dfrac{6}{n^2}+\dfrac{4}{n^3}-\dfrac{1}{n^4}}{\dfrac{3}{n}-\dfrac{3}{n^2}+\dfrac{1}{n^3}}$. Multiplying by $n$ on the top and bottom yields $\dfrac{4-\dfrac{6}{n}+\dfrac{4}{n^2}-\dfrac{1}{n^3}}{3-\dfrac{3}{n}+\dfrac{1}{n^2}}$. Then the limit is easier to evaluate. Any term with a division by $n$ will drop out as $n\to \infty$.

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1-\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^4}{1-\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^3}=\dfrac{4-0+0-0}{3-0+0}=\dfrac{4}{3}$

Comment: I took the liberty to edit the answer for better readability. See if it's fine.

Comment: Looks better to me.

Answer (score 5):

*Hint:* $\dfrac{1-x^4}{1-x^3}= \dfrac{(1-x)(1 + x + x^2 + x^3))}{(1-x)(1+x+x^2)} = \dfrac{1 + x + x^2 + x^3}{1 + x+ x^2}$ (provided $x \neq 1$.)

Now put $x = 1 - \frac{1}{n}$ and take $n \to \infty.$

Comment: It's going to take a lot of work to sort this out if you're putting $1-\frac{1}{n}$ into every $x$ position.

Comment: @BenjaminRoycraft: not necessarily!! $x_n \to x \Rightarrow x_n^2 \to x^2, x_n^3 \to x^3.$ these are standard facts. but if you don't want to use these and want more elementary method, then yours answer is the best one.

Comment: Yes, you're right. For some reason, I thought your final form was still indeterminate. You can directly evaluate the limit from your final expression.